# Nonetype has no attribute get item in python, but can see value in source page and call worked on same format

Tags: python, json, attributes, format, nonetype

So my code is giving me the error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**' which I know has been addressed before. However, I am doing the same operation in the same loop twice before with no issue whatsoever, and there are definitely times when there are no answers to the synonym pull. The definition pull however, should always return an answer. Since the source is in the same format (ran over a line, but that should read the same to a computer) I cannot forget out why the error is occurring. Below is the code I'm using and a snippet from the source. Thanks!

Source:

```
links: {                                                               
nextPage: http://data.bioontology.org/ontologies/ICO/classes?page=2,
prevPage": null                                                                                        
},
-collection: [                                                                
-{
prefLabel: "document act", 

synonym: [ ],

-definition: [
"A social act creating, revoking or transferring a socio-legal generically dependent continuant or a role by validating (signing, stamping, publishing) a document."
],
```

Python Program

```
import urllib2
import json

REST_URL = "http://data.bioontology.org"
API_KEY = "0640b94d-63f7-49f3-9be5-f79354797620"


def get_json(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]
    return json.loads(opener.open(url).read())

# Get all ontologies from the REST service and parse the JSON
ontologies = get_json(REST_URL+"/ontologies")

# Iterate looking for ontology with acronym BRO
ont = None
for ontology in ontologies:
    if ontology["acronym"] == "ICO":
        ont = ontology

labels = []
synonyms=[]
definitions=[]

# Using the hypermedia link called `classes`, get the first page
page = get_json(ont["links"]["classes"])

# Iterate over the available pages adding labels from all classes
# When we hit the last page, the while loop will exit
next_page = page
while next_page:
    next_page = page["links"]["nextPage"]
    for ont_class in page["collection"]:
        labels.append(ont_class["prefLabel"])
        synonyms.append(ont_class["synonym"])
        #if bro_class["definition"] is not None:
        definitions.append(ont_class)["definition"]

    if next_page:
        page = get_json(next_page)

# Output the labels
#for label in labels:
 #   print label
#for synonym in synonyms:
 #   print synonym
#for definition in definitions:
 #   print definition
```

Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Godjira/PycharmProjects/NCBO-REST/get_all.py", line 38, in 
    definitions.append(ont_class)["definition"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Which line is triggering the exception? Can you place the traceback in the question above? Because your code does not show an explicit `.getItem` method for any object.

Comment: definitions.append(ont_class)["definition"]  triggers the error. Here's the traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Godjira/PycharmProjects/NCBO-REST/get_all.py", line 38, in <module>
    definitions.append(ont_class)["definition"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be

```
definitions.append(ont_class["definition"])
```

Comment: ....I absolutely cannot believe I missed that. It's one of those, I've looked at it too much and needed fresh eyes. Thank you! That did it!

Comment: After `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute`, the good question is which function call returned None? In your case it was `definitions.append()`, because `list.append()` returns None. Hence the bug finding.